# how can i add a js code to my iphone app in xcode

Tags: javascript, iphone, xcode

i want to use a chart in my iphone app. i find pretty good charts written in javascript. but i couldn't find out how to add and use it in my app?

by the way, itried google chart apis but needs internet.
and i tried core-plot but didn't like much :(. i want to use javascript in my app...
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a UIWebView to your iPhone app.  You can run almost any Javascript inside it by using the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: method, and have it render the results into the webview, which you can show in your UIView.

The [phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/) source code has an example of how to do this with large JS applets